# Android - actionbar back icon change

Tags: android-actionbar

I'm doing a project. I am using SlidingMenu in my project. When i open the sliding menu, action back button icon's should seems like this image <-- also when i close action back button icon's should seems like this image --> . How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can change it programmatically easily by using homeAsUpIndicator() function that added in android API level 18 and upper.

ActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);

In case, if you are using support library,

getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);